# mysql insert into and select in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql

how do I combine the mysql insert and select statement into a prepared statement?? Will this part of the code help me to duplicate information into a database when I hit the "copy" button?

Thanks.

```
INSERT INTO assignment_speeches_copy (id, subject, body, tags, image)
SELECT * FROM assignment_speeches
WHERE id = $id";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO assignment_speeches_copy VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"); (how do I continue?)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to combine anything. [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) is a simple statement....

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare(
    "INSERT INTO assignment_speeches_copy (id, subject, body, tags, image) 
        SELECT (id, subject, body, tags, image) 
           FROM assignment_speeches 
           WHERE id = ?"
    );
```

Comment: What about the bind param after the prepare statement? Do I need it?

Comment: Like this? $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);

Comment: I have tried the bind_param yet there was an error. "Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\1102824H\Assignment2\copyspeech.php on line 35" Why?

Comment: @user2646948 Very probably `$stmt->prepare()` returned FALSE as there was some error while preparing the statement. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php Are you sure of the name of your tables and/or the various columns involved? Could you edit you question to show how where the various relevant table created? Could you edit your question to show the 3-4 lines of PHP where you prepare, bind & execute your statement?